# Appending onto Raw_input

Tags: python, file-handling

In my code, I have the user input a file name. I would like to append .txt to the end of their input, so they don't have to. (*filename vs filename.txt*) I've tried a couple different methods, but here is my current (not working) version.

```
from twitter_keys import *

import requests

# Load the UID list

filetype = ".txt"

filename = raw_input("Copy/Paste the Filename here: "), filetype

with open (filename, "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

print data
```

Looking at my debugger, I see *how* it's not working, but I can't find a good solution on how I should better go about it.

Debugger output:

```
print filename
('StrangeBeacons-20180718-144446-followers', '.txt')
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I'm probably not asking the right question when I search for posts or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filename = raw_input("Copy/Paste the Filename here: ") + filetype
```

add a '+' sign

Comment: See, I knew I was way over complicating my search. Thank you for this quick and easy fix.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as so!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. I generally use `"{}{}".format(filename,filetype)`, but you can also use `filename+filetype` or `"%s%s" % (filename, filetype)`. You might want to do some validation to make sure that they don't already have a file extension, such as

```
if not "." in filename[-5:]:
           filename = "{}{}".format(filename,filetype)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from twitter_keys import *

import requests

# Load the UID list

filetype = ".txt"

filename = raw_input("Copy/Paste the Filename here: ")

with open (filename+filetype, "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()

print data
```

As from your debugger input you can clearly see that the filename is getting converted into a tuple because of your wrong use of `,`.
You use `+` to concatenate strings.